# Distributing python packages to an online repo without exposing source code

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, linux, package

So my problem is as follows. I have an online repository where I host my package. I'd like my end user to install it using:
`pip install git + ssh`

The source code is written in C and I would like for the users to not be given access to it. Is it possible to package a wheel out of pre-existing binary outputs of CMake?

Follow up question: if I push a wheel to the repo, how do I get pip install to install the wheel? what does my `setup.py` look like?